# How can i make this between query to find different values in the same column?

Tags: php, mysql

So i store different type of measurements in a column named value

> `` (select count(*) from `lara_measurements` inner join `lara_users_measurement` on `lara_measurements`.`id` = `lara_users_measurement`.`measurement_id` where `lara_users_measurement`.`user_id` = `lara_users`.`id` and `value` between 160 cm and 165 cm and `value` between 46 kg and 52 kg) ``

But since these values use the same column, using **AND** does not work, it only works if only one between query is executed

i was searching around a lot but did not find anything.

Anybody could give me a hint?

Comment: That's not even SQL. What are you posting here?

Comment: Exactly how is `\`value\`` supposed to be BOTH height and weight?

Comment: Use OR instead. It is logical you cannot find records between values 160-165 and between values 46-52.

Comment: tried that, sadly gives false results @MrSmith

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Mysql LIKE command to find anything using wildcards :)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'b%';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly. Try:

`` (select count(*) from `lara_measurements` inner join `lara_users_measurement` on `lara_measurements`.`id` = `lara_users_measurement`.`measurement_id` where `lara_users_measurement`.`user_id` = `lara_users`.`id` and (`value` between 160 cm and 165 cm or `value` between 46 kg and 52 kg)) ``
Sorry, if it's the wrong idea, but its hard to tell exactly what you want.